# python - how to parse a string with a franction to get the numbers on both sides of '/'

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

i am trying to parse a string in python that contains a fraction where i need to store the numbers on both sides of the fraction as different variables. It works for single digit on both sides but when there are double digits, I am just getting the '/' symbol for one number and only the first number of the second part. The input file looks like this:

```
product/productId: B001EO5QW8
review/userId: AOVROBZ8BNTP7
review/profileName: S. Potter
**review/helpfulness: 19/19**
review/score: 4.0
```

my code looks like this:

```
if 'review/helpfulness' in line:
    helpline = line.rstrip().split(': ')[1:] 
    number_voted = helpline[0][0]
    number_rated = helpline[0][2]
```

and I get this for an answer:

```
NumHelpfulVotes         NumVotes
   1                       /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to further split by a slash:

```
numbers = line.split(':')[1].strip().split("/")
# ['19', '19']
```

Another solution is to use regular expression search:

```
import re 
numbers = re.findall("(\d+)/(\d+)", line)[0]
#('19', '19')
```